# Java gives filealreadyexistsexception when trying to copy files and directories recursively

Tags: java, recursion, directory, copy

I'm working on creating a recursive function that will allow me to copy contents of a directory including sub directories and their contents. The function I have written seems to copy everything, but I seem to still get an error in the console that says java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: C:\Users\Vinny\Desktop\testing\testfolder2.

My source folder is called `testfolder` and the folder I'm copying into is called `testing`.
Source folder file contents is as follows:

- testfolder

  - testfolder2

    - testfile2.txt
  - testfile.txt

Very simple folder/files.

My recursive code is this : (please note that my code is not yet cleaned up)

```
public void copyFiles(File src, Files dst) throws IOException {
  // We will start by listing all subdirectories and files
  String[] files = src.list();

  // Loop through each file / directory
  for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    // Check if the file is a directory
    if (new File(src + "\\" + files[i]).isDirectory()) {
      // We have a directory, so we will make sure the dst folder has the same sub folders
      if (Files.notExists(new File(dst + "\\" + files[i]).toPath(), LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
        // If directory does not exist, we shall create it
        new File(dst + "\\" + files[i]).mkdir();
      }
      // Go into that subdirectory and copy all its contents as well
      copyFiles(new File(src + "\\" + files[i]), new File(dst + "\\" + files[i]));
    }
    // Copy the files
    Files.copy(new File(src + "\\" + files[i]).toPath(), new File(dst + "\\" + files[i]).toPath());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Files.copy()` call works for a directory when the target does not exist. You have missed off "else". Once a directory tree is copied you follow through to `Files.copy` for the folder src -> dest.

```
else
   // Copy the files
   Files.copy(new File(src + "\\" + files[i]).toPath(), new File(dst + "\\" + files[i]).toPath());
```

Rather than mix `File`+`Path`+`Files` you can also perform recursive copy to new destination using `Files.find`:

```
public static void copy(Path src, Path dest) throws IOException {
    try(var stream = Files.find(src, Integer.MAX_VALUE, (p,a) -> true /* or other condition */)) {
        stream.forEach(p -> copyItem(p, dest.resolve(src.relativize(p))));
    }
}
private static Path copyItem(Path p, Path target) {
    // System.out.println("Files.copy("+p + ", "+target+")");
    try {
        // Drop REPLACE_EXISTING here if want existing files to be preserved
        Files.copy(p, target, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
    return target;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So after using the eclipse java debugger I've realized that after I create the directory, it also tries to copy it when doing Files.copy. I just had to place the Files.copy into an else statement when checking if it's a directory.